# Creating a stripe one-time charge coupon. Recommended way to implement "who pays"?

Tags: stripe-payments, coupon

We are writing a Stripe system for coupons.
We have Customers, Providers, and our client's Company as the platform. The Providers are Standalone accounts.

We found a bunch of answers on how we need to be taking the discount on our end.

What is the recommended method for the Company/Platform to fund the discount (as a marketing cost), so the Provider still gets paid what they earned and they are incentivized to share their coupons (without being paid less)?

Should we just create an extra charge that is essentially the Company reimbursing the Customer? So if the charge is 10.00 and the discount is 1.00, the customer still pays the provider 10.00. But we note in the charge that the Customer will receive a reimbursement for coupon code X, and then we make a charge where the platform pays the Customer 1.00. Basically leaving the provider out so they still get paid in full.

Comment: Flow of funds have a lot of rules that you need to follow and you'll want to talk to Stripe directly about your exact business model and how to build this. What you want is definitely not this though but instead to use Special Case Transfers: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers

Comment: @koopajah just as a follow up in case anyone is searching for this. I talked to stripe and they recommend (and confirm what koopajah says) that the second transfer (1 out of the 10 dollars above example), be a special case transfer. And the good thing about this, is that it can be linked to the one-off charge so it is all traceable and funded by the Platform/Company. Note that these are indeed special case, and cannot exceed 10% of the total money exchanged on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

@koopajah answered in the comments, so marking it answered.

Use a special case transfer for this, and do NOT exceed 10% of the total platform income with these types of transfer. Stripe told us that they regulate this.